# Remotely installing msi on different windows nodes?

Tags: windows, chef-infra

I have an MSI I want to occasionally install on remote windows nodes in my cluster. What is the easiest and least overhead way of doing this?

I've looked into chef, but it seems like I need an entire server just to manage different nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Chef's `windows_package` resource is used to install MSIs. If you're on a very old version you might need the `windows` cookbook for it, but we pulled MSI support in maybe ~12.0 I think? Check the release notes if you have to be certain, but anything remotely recent has it in core.

Comment: Ah, cool. I didn't realize it was native at this point. The problem with chef is there is a centralized server. I don't want to manage that overhead and just want to distribute from a centralized source.

Comment: Then use chef-solo?